# Save an Object[][] and load it

Tags: java, object, save, load

I currently have an `Object[][]` that holds a 2D array, this array will be manipulated using temporary arrays and what not to increase the size (it's what I have figured out so far).

What I want to happen is when the program exits the new `Object[][]` instance is saved and then when it starts up I want that new `Object[][]` to load. I'm thinking about making it a file then use a tokenizer to fill the `Object[][]` in the start. Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: if your program exits, the object is obviously lost. You need to save it's information somewhere, eg: as a json file, have a look at Googles gson, it's pretty simple https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: Take a look at [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). [This tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/objectinputstream/java-objectinputstream-and-objectoutputstream-example/) may also help.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I was able to figure out how to save and load the Object[][].

To save the file I would first have to have an Object[][] variable that contained at least one Object array. Then I saved/created the file, like so:

```
public void saveFile(Object[] variable){
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
                FileOutputStream(filename));
        oos.writeObject(variable);
        oos.close();

}
```

then load it as such:

```
 public void loadFile(){
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new
            FileInputStream(filename));
    players = (Object[][]) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
 }
```

I know I'm simply overwriting the file with a new but it's the best solution I was able to figure out. Thank you @MasterBlaster for your help, and @MadMatts I just could not figure out how to use gson, maybe I will another time, but thank you none the less!